# How can I fetch a word from this JSON file

Tags: json, jq

I want to fetch `type` results from this JSON file. How can I do this?

```
{
    "inputs": [{
        "title": "vault_beats",
        "global": true,
        "name": "Beats",
        "content_pack": null,
        "created_at": "2019-01-11T05:31:49.720Z",
        "type": "org.graylog.plugins.beats.Beats2Input",
        "creator_user_id": "admin",
        "attributes": {
            "recv_buffer_size": 1048576,
            "tcp_keepalive": false,
            "number_worker_threads": 1,
            "tls_client_auth_cert_file": "",
            "beats_prefix": false,
            "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
            "tls_cert_file": "",
            "port": 5044,
            "tls_key_file": "admin",
            "tls_enable": false,
            "tls_key_password": "admin",
            "tls_client_auth": "disabled",
            "override_source": null
        },
        "static_fields": {},
        "node": null,
        "id": "5c382a45590801001d742017"
    }, {
        "title": "vault_beatsl",
        "global": true,
        "name": "GELF TCP",
        "content_pack": null,
        "created_at": "2019-01-11T05:32:05.869Z",
        "type": "org.graylog2.inputs.gelf.tcp.GELFTCPInput",
        "creator_user_id": "admin",
        "attributes": {
            "recv_buffer_size": 1048576,
            "tcp_keepalive": false,
            "use_null_delimiter": true,
            "number_worker_threads": 1,
            "tls_client_auth_cert_file": "",
            "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
            "tls_cert_file": "",
            "decompress_size_limit": 8388608,
            "port": 12201,
            "tls_key_file": "admin",
            "tls_enable": false,
            "tls_key_password": "admin",
            "max_message_size": 2097152,
            "tls_client_auth": "disabled",
            "override_source": null
        },
        "static_fields": {},
        "node": null,
        "id": "5c382a55590801001d74202b"
    }],
    "total": 2
}
```

Sample Output:-

```
"type":"org.graylog.plugins.beats.Beats2Input"
"type":"org.graylog2.inputs.gelf.tcp.GELFTCPInput"
```

Comment: If it is prettified JSON (that means `type:` is in a separate line ), you just need to grep for it.

Comment: not in a separate line

Comment: Use awk; it allows you to define row separators(RS) and field separators(FS). Try something like - `awk 'BEGIN {RS=",";}1' one.json` which splits all keys into separate lines and then grep the required field you want.

Comment: In future, if you ask a question at SO, please specify the requirements more precisely.  Showing your attempts at a solution often helps clarify the requirements as well.

Comment: its working fine with awk thanks

Comment: @YvetteColomb - I am not sure why you deleted Dmitry's answer, which seems to me to be appropriate and indeed fine in all respects.  Since you are a moderator, I am not sure how to request the response be "undeleted" so I am appealing to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements are a bit fuzzy but when used with the -r command-line option, the following produces the desired output and has the advantage of simplicity, but you might want to tweak it to meet your exact requirements:

```
.. | objects | select(.type) | "\"type\":\"\(.type)\""
```